# MPAndroidChart: How to format BarEntry as a String?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a horizontal bar chart with X values. Right now I only can create a BarEntry with a float value like this:

```
BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry( (float )iAmountInCents / 100, ++ index,item.getKey());
valueSet1.add(barEntry);
```

I also added a **custom formatter**:

```
 public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements YAxisValueFormatter {

        private DecimalFormat mFormat;

        public MyYAxisValueFormatter () {
            mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis) {
            // write your logic here
            // access the YAxis object to get more information
            return  "₹. " + mFormat.format(value) ;
        }
    }

 YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter());

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter());
```

But the getFormattedValue() method is NEVER called 
which results in something like this on a bar in the chart: 0.400. I want that value on the bar chart to look like this  "$ .40" . How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the formatter at a wrong place. You are setting formatter on the YAxis. Instead you need to set the formatter on the BarDataSet object that you are assigning to the chart.

Create a Formatter class extending from `ValueFormatter`

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $";
    }
}
```

You have to put the formatter whenever you assign the data set to the chart using

```
BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "DataSet 1");
set1.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```